# Open a file with java and maven

Tags: java, maven

I don't know how to properly access files from java when using maven. I know there are a lot of other questions/answers out there very similar to this but i haven't been able to get any of them to work for me.

Right now i have the code file i hope to be opening the data files with in this directory:

```
maven_project/src/main/java/project/package/source_file.java
```

in the pom.xml i'm including the resources like so:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources/question_contents</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*.json</include>
        </includes>
     </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

The resource files are correctly being coppied to

```
 maven_project/target/classes
```

the command i'm using to build right now is

```
 mvn package
```

If it matters, i'm using linux

I am willing to change any aspect of this setup in order to open files.

I would prefer to open them as a `FileInputStream` but i can work with anything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I tried the answers in the suggested duplicate question, still no luck. Something that i didn't think about before was that this is being done in a method in a abstract class, idk what impact that would  have on the refrences to `this` .

Also i know this worked at one point. Before moving everything to maven i had everything lumped in one folder, there were no issues.

Comment: Why are you add the resources configuration which is already default so no need to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Since you set up Maven to properly include the resource files in your build, you can access them using the class loader

```
InputStream in = 
  SomeClassInTheSamePackage.class.getResourceAsStream("filename.json");

// or using full path starting from slash

in = SomeClassAnywhereInYourProject.class.getResourceAsStream(
    "/question_contents/filename.json");
```

Comment: Neither is working for me. I'm still just getting Errors, filename does not exist

Answer (score 1):

`getClassLoader()` will help you in getting the file. Include the file in `resources` folder in `maven` project and use following to read the file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName), "UTF8"));
```

Replace `fileName` with your actual fileName. Now, you can use `br` to read file line-by-line.

Comment: `Errors, filename.json does not exist`
That's all i see. Everything else works.

Comment: Can you check if you have placed `filename.json` in resources folder? Also, please share your project folder structure in expanded mode by editing the question